# $state , {reload:true} not working: angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
.state('app.sr.product', {
            name: 'product info',
            url: '/product/:productRef/:productSerialNumber',
            data: {
                products:[]
            },
            views: {
                "rootContainer": {
                    templateUrl: 'views/product/product.html',
                    controller: 'ProductCtrl',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                }
            }
        })
```

In the above code when application comes to `"app.sr.product"` state , I set the value of `$state.current.data.products=array_value`.

When a user logs out from the application (below is the code)

```
function logout() {
        clearLocalStorage();
        $state.go('app.sr.home', { reload: true});
 }
```

When it comes to Home view , page is not getting reloaded(when user clicks on logout link) and because of that 
`$state.current.data.products` still holds the same value, it should set it to blank array.

Any suggestions, help is appreciated!!!

Thanks

Comment: [Read the fine manual](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_go)... the *options* are the 3rd argument ~ `$state.go('app.sr.home', null, {reload: true})`

Comment: Not working I tried that one